# Explain Microsoft Desktop Optimization Pack Licensing

Tags: licensing, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

There are lots of tools in the Microsoft Desktop Optimization Pack (MDOP) that would be really useful.

However, the licensing on it is amazingly unclear.  I thought I understood Microsoft licensing until I saw MDOP.

Can anyone explain how MDOP is licensed?

For instance, can I install a DEM server if I only have one (well five's the minimum, I guess) PC on Software Assurance, or does every PC I connect to DEM have to have SA on the OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.microsoftvolumelicensing.com/userights/ProductPage.aspx?pid=244) is the only thing I could find for MDOP licensing. Microsoft licensing, as I replied on your previous, also Microsoft related question, is convoluted and has many, many, many variations.

That being said, and because I had also become curious about this, I called Microsoft Licensing. They directed me to [a document](http://www.microsoftvolumelicensing.com/userights/Downloader.aspx?DocumentId=2235), and to page 102, which reads:

> "Active Windows Vista Business Software
>   Assurance coverage provides you with
>   eligibility to acquire licenses for
>   MDOP for Software Assurance.  These
>   licenses are an optional and separate
>   purchase from Software Assurance. See
>   the Product List for details.  If you
>   invoke this benefit, you have the
>   rights below for each MDOP for
>   Software Assurance license you
>   acquire."

I hope this shed some light (it didn't for me though, but I am not remotely interested on MDOP anymore).

Comment: Perfect - it's an extra product you buy if you already have Windows Desktop with SA as an add-on.